# How can I access a shapes style and change it through PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, shapes, cpu-word

I am trying to change the style of a bunch of shapes in one document. I have looked at the available properties of the shapes I want to change by printing them out to an html file. I have used MSDN's documentation to do some more research on these properties but have so far not had any luck with it working. I am fairly new to PowerShell, so there may be something I am misunderstanding about accessing properties.

I came across [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.shape.shapestyle) on Microsoft's website. I tried to do what they were doing, but kept coming back with errors like, "Add-Type : Cannot add type. The assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Core' could not be found," and "Unable to find type [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdPresetLineDash]," where I imagine the two are related. I tried adding the Assembly, but that didn't help either.

I have tried this:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.Core
    # Open the document
    $doc = $word.Documents.Open($input)
    $shapes = $doc.Shapes
    foreach ($shape in $doc.Shapes) {
        if($shape.Name -like "Straight Arrow Connector*"){
            $red = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information]::RGB(255, 0, 0)
            $shape.Line.ForeColor.RGB = $red.ToArgb()
            $shape.ShapeStyle = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word]::MsoPresetLineDash
        }

    }
```

I have also used the styles that are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.msoshapestyleindex), by doing something like this:

`$shape.ShapeStyle = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word]::msoLineStylePreset1`

However, I get the same errors.

I also noticed on the html printout of the properties for the shape, I have the following line:

`System.__ComObject#{000209a0-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}  ShapeStyle  Property    MsoShapeStyleIndex ShapeStyle () {get} {set}`

Does this mean I should be using ShapeStyle(msoLineStylePreset1)?

Comment: Open MSWord, then your doc. Start the Macro recorder, then do what you need to in Word.  Stop the Macro Recorder to see the VBA created. Refactor that VBA code into calls from PowerShell.

Comment: I like this approach, and thanks for the response, but the document I am working out of will not allow me to select the shape I am trying to change. 

I also tried to do it in a new document, record the macro, and then apply that macro to the old document, but it did not recognize the shape. 

Could this be due to the age of the document? I updated it to a .docx file, but perhaps the shapes did not update or something?

Edit: I can select the shape when I am not recording the macro, but there is no way to select the shape once I hit record.